# Куда tar сохраняет архивы?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Если я напишу в корне команду:

> tar -czvf name-of-archive.tar.gz /path/to/directory-or-file

То в корне не появится архив. А если к названию архива приставлю `/`, то архив будет сохранён в корне. **Вопрос:** если не указан корень, то в какой директории сохраняется архив?

Comment: В текущей смотрели?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов текущая папка - корень. В нём ничего не появляется, если в названии вначале не поставить `/`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin однозначно в текущей. И странно, но чтобы писать что-то в корневую папку нужны права рута. С '/' точно пишется?

Comment: @tilin работаю из-под root. Да, точно пишется. А если `/` не ставить, что-то куда-то пишется, но куда - не известно.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin у меня Ubuntu 16.04 команда `sudo tar -czvf name-of-archive.tar.gz путь_к_файлу` нормально создает архив в корне? когда текущая папка тоже корень

Comment: файл находится там, где вы указали. в данном случае вы указали создать его в текущем каталоге (это наследуемое свойство процесса).

Comment: если *"текущая папка - корень"*, то `name.tar.gz` и `/name.tar.gz` это один и тот же файл.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Думаю проблма вопроса в неверном переводе (понимании терминологии) root - супер пользователь, "корень" обычно не переводят на русский, так и говорят рут имеет свой "домашнюю" директорю "/root". root directory - корневой каталок начала пути для абсолютных путей - обозначается "/"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если под рутом работаешь - значит в `/root` смотри. У него тоже есть домашний каталог и скорее всего ты в нём и находишься.

Можно кстати приложить выхлоп команды `pwd`.

Comment: Да. Посмотрел в `/root/`. Там и лежат мои архивы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, как Вам уже писали, команда

```
tar -czvf name-of-archive.tar.gz /path/to/directory-or-file
```

Создает архив в папке запуска.

Могу Вам посоветовать запустить find от рута, создав перед этим архив с каким-нибудть хитрым именем и поискать его.

Answer (score 2):

Вечер добрый.

Вопрос: если не указан корень, то в какой директории сохраняется архив?

Если ОС GNU/Linux  и tar - GNU tar то можно протестировать:

```
[root@base201215 /]# pwd
/
[root@base201215 /]# strace 2>&1 tar -czvf opt.tar.gz opt/ | grep "opt.tar.gz"
execve("/bin/tar", ["tar", "-czvf", "opt.tar.gz", "opt/"], 0x7fff068d1408 /* 39 vars */) = 0
```

Подсмотрим, что творится за сценой. По умолчанию tar сохраняет в $PWD

Можно жестко указать путь куда сохранять архив:

```
~$ tar -czvf /path/to/pack.tar.gz /path/to/dir_of_file
```

Сменить директорию при распаковке поможет ключ -C:

```
~# tar -xzvf pack.tar.gz -C /path/to/target/dir

-C, --directory=DIR
              Change to DIR before performing any
              operations.  This option is order-
              sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
```